# Definition of functions in $L^p$ space

Tags: definition, lp-spaces

I know that if we suppose that $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, and if $f$ is in $L^p$, then this means that $\|f\|_p=[\int_X (f^p) dx]^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

But I feel as though I'm missing some important implications when we state that $f$ is in $L^p$. What else is implied in the definition of $L^p$?

Comment: [$L^p$ spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)

Comment: The modulus in the integral (around the function) :P

Comment: Actually $f\in L^p$ means that integral is finite.  Otherwise all you've stated is the definition of $\|\cdot\|_p$

Comment: Anything else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If $X$ is a set, $\mathcal{S}$ a sigma algebra on $X$ and $\mu : \mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ a measure, then, by definition 
$$
L^p(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu) = \left\{ f:X\to \mathbb{F} : f \text{ is $\mathcal{S}$ measurable and } \int_X |f|^p d\mu < \infty \right\} 
$$
In that case, if $f \in L^p(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$, the $p$-semi norm is 
$$
\| f \|_p =\left( \int_X |f|^p d\mu \right)^{1/p} < \infty
$$
Note that you forgot to consider the modulus $|f|$ in the semi norm

Comment: @alias it is the field where the functions live, generally $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. I've made an edit and add more details, hope it is clearer

Comment: Okay, thanks, I hadn't read your comment thoroughly enough.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to help !

Comment: @Alonso-do you think you can help me with my other question?

Comment: Sure I can try ! You can ask it in this site and put the link here in the comment for mi to check it !

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308336/lp-space-corollary/1308356#1308356

Comment: @alias Done. I have put an answer. Hope it is clear.